# If I remove the Luks-encrypted drive to another motherboard, will I be able to run my system there?

Tags: linux, hard-drive, motherboard, encryption, desktop-computer

If I remove the drive to another motherboard (for example from PC to Notebook), will I be able to run my Luks-encrypted system there without any problem?

What if there are several systems on that drive? Is there no difference?

Can there be any problems by such a game. For example I will remove the drive and then put it back in the old computer where it originally worked. Can it happen that I can no longer boot it because some "settings" have changed?

Answer (score 15):

The motherboard doesn't do the encryption; the OS does, entirely in software. The volume can be unlocked for as long as you remember the passphrase.

An exception is when you use TPM to implement automatic unlock which is by design bound to a specific TPM device, but usually such volumes have the TPM only as an alternative to a regular passphrase, not as the only method.

If you're using UEFI firmware, the new board won't have the NVRAM boot entry that the old one had, and will expect the disk to have some kind of bootloader at the "default" location – but this issue has nothing to do with the presence or absence
of LUKS.

If you're using UEFI firmware, *and* you've chosen to use "EFISTUB loader" (i.e. where the NVRAM boot entry points directly at the Linux kernel), *and* that boot entry contains kernel command line parameters that were important to unlocking LUKS, then yes, the system wouldn't know what to boot and what to unlock anymore – but if you had a setup like that, you probably would know about it and wouldn't be asking. It's not the kind of setup that occurs by default.

Comment: but I did a test on new asus rog boards, 2 of the same vintage almost identical bios. I moved the m2 drive to the other board and linux 

One luks partition the other without encryption. And unfortunately no Linux will run normally. I can only select the grub recovery mode and then the system starts, when I give the normal Linux mode, the system seems to want to start but only the asus rog logo is displayed. Why?

Answer (score 6):

The short answer is "It depends - but most likely you can migrate the disk".

LUKS supports a number of ways of decrypting a drive (it has a header which accepts, from memory, up to 8 different passwords/passphrases/keys which in turn decrypt the master passphrase).   Provided you know any one of these you can unlock the drive.

While technically possible (I've done it), the drive is not normally keyed to the TPM on the motherboard. (On Ubuntu 22.04 it uses a passphrase entered at boot to unlock the drive by default if you use FDE.  This would be fairly common)

Even if the drive does rely on TPS there is normally a password alternative you can use.  If you don't have this, adding one is hard, but not impossible.  There are instructions at https://access.redhat.com/solutions/1543373 on how to manipulate the master key file and add additional keys provided you have an open LUKS device.

Comment: If I take the drive out and put it back in my old laptop ( A ), will there be any problems? What if I install a new system on my old laptop  ( A ), in the meantime, e.g. on a new hard drive? 
Will both drives work (with os) if I swap them?

Comment: That should be fine - Just to be extra safe don't turn on the device you remove the drive from while the drive is out.  realistically this shouldn't make a difference, its just to be extra safe.  (When you start a device the TPM module calculates hashes  based on hardware and softwate settings and stores these in special PCR registers that cant be changed until the unit restarts.  The PCR registers can (but in LUKS usually arn't) used as a key to unlock the drive.  [Windows Bitlocker is similar but usually uses these in one if its key slots with a backup key in another]